# Add and delete List items

Tags: monocle-scala

The university [example](https://julien-truffaut.github.io/Monocle/examples/university_example.html) explains how to add and delete items of a map:

```
(departments composeLens at("Physics")).set(Some(physics))(uni)
(departments composeLens at("History")).set(None)(uni)
```

This does not work with Lists, though:

```
(lecturers composeOptional index(2)).set(Lecturer("New", "Lecturer", 50))(dep)
(lecturers composeOptional index(0)).set(None)(dep)
```

Adding does nothing, deleting throws a compilation error.

**Edit:** By now, I use [quicklens](https://github.com/softwaremill/quicklens), which is able to modify sequences.

Comment: Probably because Lists are immutable - https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Comment: @VineetKulkarni No, that's not the reason. Monocle is designed to operate on immutable data structures.

Comment: @RobinGreen - Does the answer provided below address your question?

Comment: Well, not really - it doesn't give a definitive answer to how to add/remove items from a list using Monocle.

Comment: @RobinGreen - Assuming that is possible (and assuming that was the question...)

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no explicit question in the OP, I will try answering a couple of possible questions:

1. **Why do the first pair of lines work, and the second pair does not?**

The answer is given in ["What is the difference between at and index? When should I use one or the other?" halfway across the page](https://julien-truffaut.github.io/Monocle/faq.html):

> In other words, `index` can update any existing values while `at` can also `insert` and `delete`.

2. **How can I add/remove items to/from a List?**

Just below the text quoted above:

> Since `index` is weaker than `at`, we can implement an instance of `Index` on more data structure than `At`. For instance, `List` or `Vector` only have an instance of `Index` because there is no way to insert an element at an arbitrary index of a sequence.

So it may not be possible...
I have no Monocle here to test a few things, though.